# How to add a negative date to the timeline

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

How can I add a negative date to the timeline?
My current code is:

```
let items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'today', start: '2018-11-02'}
])

new vis.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'), items, {})
```

To add an event to the timeline, I just add it to **items**:

```
items.add({id: 2 content: 'tomorrow', start: '2018-11-03'})
```

If I zoom the timeline out I see that it shows dates before year 1. How can I add an event to a negative date, without needing to drag the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
new Date(-2018, 11, 26)
```

This will produce a negative date.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works on your lay out, but i use timestamps (if you import timestamps from php you should add 3 0's to the end as php use seconds and js use miliseconds )

but that works for me.

alternative what happens if you add this

```
items.add({id: 3 content: 'past', start: '2018-10-03'})
```

would that not show the item before current time ?